# What are the limiting factors of human stamina?

Tags: physiology, bioenergetics, exercise

What are the limiting factors of (human) stamina? Let's define stamina as the capacity to continue doing a physical activity. We clearly have our limits, so what aspects of physiology impose a limit on human physical exertion? How do these aspects work together and interact?

Great detail isn't necessary, but a concise overview is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer but in some ways your question is, as yet, unanswered. It is a bit like asking, "why do we need to sleep?" Also, there are things the body needs for energy that can run out, such as carbohydrates. However, to a limited extent we can increase our "stamina" by taking stimulants such as caffeine.

Comment: @takintoolong - An answer based on our best understanding will suffice.

Comment: You might start be defining stamina, the word covers a wide variety of factors.

Comment: It seems this review has got you covered in pretty good detail: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2375555/

Comment: Since your question is being considered too broad by some members of the community, I suggest you narrow it down to "What aspects of physiology impose a limit on human physical exertion?", and/or specifically ask for physiological quantities that correlate with the onset of perceived exhaustion.

Comment: Stamina, even if you narrow it down to a capacity to continue a physical activity, is still influenced by diverse factors, including genetic, training, diet, hormonal, psychological, religious, social...It seems that one would need to write almost a book to make "a concise overview" about how various aspects work together. If you are looking for more physical factors, do you maybe want to use the term endurance instead of stamina?

Comment: There are multiple factors as already pointed out by others. You should check out a review or a book on muscle physiology. It would be difficult to explain each and every factor that affects muscular performance.

Comment: @Jan I believe Justsnilloc is looking for the more proximal factors, what physically is happening when someone reachings their limit.

Comment: @John, yes, I get it, but I still have a big problem to decide what to focus on.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is asking for an an overview more than anything, I have been looking for my book on kinesiology but have had no luck. I can't remember the actual progression after oxygen debt and running out of glycogen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A few explanations at the cellular and molecular level:**

First, for contraction to happen, muscles need signals from nerves. Replenishing the **pool of neurotransmitters** (used for each synaptic burst) takes a bit of time, and short-term exhaustion may happen at this level.

In the muscle cells, contraction is caused by a **calcium release** within the cell, from a cellular compartment called the sarcoplasmic reticulum. This reticulum can only contain so many ions, so if the muscle contracts a lot, it will eventually need to rest for a while to re-accumulate calcium in the sarcoplasmic reticulum to prepare for more contractions.

Muscles need **molecular "fuel"** (like ATP molecules) to contract/relax. After an intense or sustained effort, these molecules are partially consumed and the muscle simply runs out of energy; it needs a bit of time to resore the pool of metabolites needed to work properly. Conversely, muscle contraction also causes the accumulation of metabolites and ions like potassium, which partially inhibit muscle contraction. Fatigue occurs when these accumulate at high level, and they must be cleared before making new efforts.

For references see:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5668469/ doi:10.1038/emm.2017.194 (general review)
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5033663/ doi:10.1249/MSS.0000000000000923 (focuses more on muscle-neuron relationships)
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9232550 Green, J Sports Sci. 1997 Jun;15(3):247-56.  (at the cellular scale)
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7715628 Williams & Klug, Muscle Nerve. 1995 Apr;18(4):421-34.(more focused on calcium)